# Overpass Turbo Select all Shops

Tags: overpass-api

I am trying to select all categories of shops for a portion of the UK.

To select just the supermarkets I would use "shop" = "supermarket", and so forth, while to select all categories I have tried "shop" = "*" but no results are returned.

Do you know how the below statements can be fixed to select all categories of shops?

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“shop”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “shop”
  node["shop" = "*"]({{bbox}});
);

// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
[out:json][timeout:250];
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “shop=*”
  node["shop"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I strongly suggest using the wizard to create your request if you're unfamiliar with the overpass-turbo/OSM syntax.